# Updating phpMyAdmin blowfish_secret via bash shell script in linux

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am working on a bash script that automatically downloads phpMyAdmin and extracts it. I would like to add one more step to this installer script.

Copy `config.sample.inc.php` as `config.inc.php` and update this file's line with a random blowfish secret:

> $cfg['blowfish_secret'] = ''; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

So, this is what I have I have tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

wget -O phpMyAdmin-4.5.3.1-english.zip https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.5.3.1/phpMyAdmin-4.5.3.1-english.zip;
unzip phpMyAdmin-4.5.3.1-english.zip >/dev/null 2>/dev/null;
cd phpMyAdmin-4.5.3.1-english;
mv * ..;
cd ..;
rm -rf phpMyAdmin-4.5.3.1-english;
rm -rf phpMyAdmin-4.5.3.1-english.zip;
randomBlowfishSecret=`openssl rand -base64 32`;
cat config.sample.inc.php | sed -e "s/cfg['blowfish_secret'] = ''/cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '$randomBlowfishSecret'/" > config.inc.php
```

When this script runs, phpMyAdmin is downloaded and extracted and the file is copied, however it does not appear to be setting the `randomBlowfishSecret` to `$cfg['blowfish_secret']`.

Any ideas?

Comment: You probably want to escape `[]` in the regex: `cfg\['blowfish...` to tell sed that they're not for character classes.

Comment: Are those the only characters i need to escape?

Comment: I'd say so: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

Comment: You don't need `cat`, btw: `cat file | sed "s/x/y" > output` is the same as `sed "s/x/y" file > output` and doesn't spawn a subshell.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I tried escaping the `[]` and it has not worked, the `config.inc.php` file is empty. In your `sed` only example, what are `s/x/y` params?

Comment: ^ Should be `sed "s/x/y/"` both times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few points:

- You don't have to end your lines with `;` – a newline has the same effect.
- If you want to redirect both stdout and stderr, you can use `&>/dev/null` instead of `>/dev/null 2>/dev/null`, but in the case of `unzip`, you can just use `unzip -q` to suppress output (or even `-qq`, but `-q` was already silent for me).
- Instead of

  ```
  cd phpMyAdmin-4.5.3.1-english;
  mv * ..;
  cd ..;
  ```

  you can just use `mv phpMyAdmin-4.5.3.1-english/* .`
- There are two files starting with `.`, which aren't moved with your command (unless you have the `dotglob` shell option set), so you have to move them separately:

  ```
  mv phpMyAdmin-4.5.3.1-english/.*.yml .
  ```
- The `phpMyAdmin-4.5.3.1-english` is now empty, so you can remove it with `rmdir` instead of `rm -rf` (which would have let you know that it's not empty yet).
- `phpMyAdmin-4.5.3.1-english.zip` is just a file; no need to recursively delete it, `rm -f` is enough.
- Instead of the deprecated backticks for command substitution, you could use the more modern `$()`:

  ```
  randomBlowfishSecret=$(openssl rand -base64 32)
  ```
- The `sed` can be improved in three ways:

  - [No need for `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat). `cat file | sed "s/x/y/g" > output` (replace all `x` in `file` with `y`, save to `output`) is equivalent to `sed "s/x/y/g" file > output`, but the latter doesn't spawn an extra subshell.
  - Your regular expression

    ```
    s/cfg['blowfish_secret'] = ''/
    ```

    is interpreted as "`cfg`, and the any ONE character from the list between `[` and `]`", but you want literal `[` and `]`, so they have to be escaped: `\[` and `\]`. In the replacement string, they don't have to be escaped.
  - The password generated by `openssl rand` can contain forward slashes, which confuses sed. You can use a different delimiter for sed, for example `"s|x|y|"` instead of `"s/x/y/"`.

**All of these are cosmetic, except the last two sed bullet points: those can break the script.** Well, and the missing hidden files might be annoying, too.

Cleaned up version that works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

wget -O phpMyAdmin-4.5.3.1-english.zip https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.5.3.1/phpMyAdmin-4.5.3.1-english.zip
unzip -q phpMyAdmin-4.5.3.1-english.zip
mv phpMyAdmin-4.5.3.1-english/* .
mv phpMyAdmin-4.5.3.1-english/.*.yml .
rmdir phpMyAdmin-4.5.3.1-english
rm -f phpMyAdmin-4.5.3.1-english.zip
randomBlowfishSecret=$(openssl rand -base64 32)
sed -e "s|cfg\['blowfish_secret'\] = ''|cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '$randomBlowfishSecret'|" config.sample.inc.php > config.inc.php
```